# Leaderboard toplist with current userid in center - SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table:

```
+---------+------------+----------+-------+
| userId  | campaignId | countryId| points| 
+---------+------------+----------+-------+
|      10 | 1          |      101 |    72 |
|       3 | 1          |      101 |    30 |
|       6 | 1          |      101 |    72 |
|       4 | 1          |      101 |    49 |
|       1 | 1          |      101 |    53 |
|       8 | 1          |      101 |    67 |
|       5 | 1          |      101 |     6 |
|       7 | 1          |      101 |    87 |
|       2 | 1          |      101 |    41 |
|      11 | 1          |      101 |    76 |
|       9 | 1          |      101 |    50 |
+---------+------------+----------+-------+
```

I have already created a leaderboard toplist with a query like this:

```
    select 
       RANK() OVER(order by T.points desc) AS rowRank,
          T.UserID, T.points
        from table as T 
        where T.campaignId=@campaignId
OFFSET (@page-1)*@limit ROWS FETCH NEXT @limit ROWS ONLY
```

Above query returns a regular toplist from top to bottom.

However, next requirement is to create a leaderboard toplist that returns current user Id rank + the above 2 ranked users + the 2 below ranked users, in total 5 users should be listed with current user in the center.

So additional input parameters would be:

```
set @userId = 8 // current user where leader board should center around
set @maxTopLimit = 2 // include 2 users ranked above current user
set @maxBottomLimit = 2 // include 2 users ranked below current user
```

The leaderboard returned should look like this with userId **8** in the center

```
        +---------+------------+----------+-------+---------|
        | userId  | campaignId | countryId| points| rowRank |
        +---------+------------+----------+-------+---------+
        |      11 | 1          |      101 |    76 |   3     |
        |      10 | 1          |      101 |    72 |   4     |
   #####|###### 8 | 1 #########|##### 101 |### 67 |## 5 ####|########
        |       9 | 1          |      101 |    50 |   6     |
        |       2 | 1          |      101 |    49 |   7     |
        +---------+------------+----------+-------+------+--+
```

How do I write a SQL query that behaves like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Move the ranking results in a subquery or common table expression.
   `with cte_rank as (...)`
2. Select the target user.
   `from cte_rank cr where cr.UserId = @userId`
3. Join the target row with all rows in the defined interval.
   `join cte_rank cr2 on cr2.RowRank >= cr.RowRank - @before and cr2.RowRank <= cr.RowRank + @after`
4. Select all rows from the interval.
   `select cr2.*`

**Sample data**

```
create table CampaignPoints
(
  UserId int,
  CampaignId int,
  CountryId int,
  Points int
);

insert into CampaignPoints (UserId, CampaignId, CountryId, Points) values
(10, 1, 101, 72),
( 3, 1, 101, 30),
( 6, 1, 101, 72),
( 4, 1, 101, 49),
( 1, 1, 101, 53),
( 8, 1, 101, 67),
( 5, 1, 101,  6),
( 7, 1, 101, 87),
( 2, 1, 101, 41),
(11, 1, 101, 76),
( 9, 1, 101, 50);
```

**Solution**

```
declare @userId int = 8;
declare @before int = 2;
declare @after  int = 2;

with cte_rank as
(
  select cp.UserId,
         cp.CampaignId,
         cp.CountryId,
         cp.Points,
         rank() over(order by cp.Points desc) as RowRank
  from CampaignPoints cp
)
select cr2.*
from cte_rank cr
join cte_rank cr2
  on  cr2.RowRank >= cr.RowRank - @before
  and cr2.RowRank <= cr.RowRank + @after
where cr.UserId = @userId
order by cr2.RowRank;
```

**Result**

```
UserId  CampaignId  CountryId  Points  RowRank
------  ----------  ---------  ------  ------- 
10      1           101        72      3
 6      1           101        72      3
 8      1           101        67      5
 1      1           101        53      6
 9      1           101        50      7
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=83af69ba8d0b7909fe6d1ee1397910ee) to see things in action.